# object java AssertEquals Same not returning true when compareTo shows they're equal

Tags: java, junit

This shows the class with attributes to reference
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/65623190?noredirect=1

Product.class

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Goods o) {
    int compared = 0;
    System.out.println("Date " + o.getDate() + " " + this.getDate());
    if(o.getDate() != this.getDate()) {
        compared = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Price " + o.getPrice() + " " + this.getPrice());
    if(Double.compare(o.getPrice(), this.getPrice()) != 0) {
        compared = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Status " + o.getStatus() + " " + this.getStatus());
    if(o.getStatus() != this.getStatus()) {
        compared = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Name " + o.getProductName() + " " + this.getProductName());
    if(o.getProductName() != this.getProductName()) {
        compared = 1;
    }

        if(o.getDate().equals(this.getDate()) &&
                o.getStatus().equals(this.getStatus()) &&
                o.getProductName().equals(this.getProductName()) &&
                o.getPrice().equals(this.getPrice())) {
            compared = 0;
        }
    return compared;
}
```

JunitTest.class

```
@Test
public Test {
    Product product = new Product();    
    product.setProductName("Product_A");
    product.setPrice(4.10);
    product.setStatus(Library.STATUSES.THEM);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
    date = calendar.getTime();
    product.setDate(date);

    actualGoods.add(product);
    product = new Product();
    product.setProductName("Product_A");
    product.setPrice(3.70);
    product.setDate(date);
    product.setStatus(Library.STATUSES.HIM);
    expectedGoods.add(product);

    assertSame(expectedGoods, classLib.ProductUpdate(actualGoods, Library.STATUSES.HIM));
 }
```

Then I have my method that replaces the cheaper product and moves the status into the 'HIM' status in my Library class

```
public List<Product> redLinePromotionListStatusUpdate(List<Product> actualProduct, STATUSES status) {
    List<Product> currentProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Product> originalStatusProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    int listIndex = 0;

    if(actualProduct != null) {
        for (Product product : actualProduct) {
            if (product.getStatus().toString().equals(STATUSES.THEM.toString())) {
                originalStatusProducts.add(listIndex, product);
                listIndex++;
            }
            if (product.getStatus().equals(STATUSES.valueOf(status.toString())) && containsName(originalStatusProducts, product.getProductName())) {
                if ((callReductionPrice(product.getPrice(), originalStatusProducts.get(originalStatusProducts.size() - 1).getPrice())) < originalStatusProducts.get(originalStatusProducts.size() - 1).getPrice()) {
                    currentProducts.add(product);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return currentProducts;
}
```

Some how I am getting that my two objects are not equal.  When I use the class method compareTo I get that they are so it's losing equvilence in my Library class method somewhere.

**EDIT**

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[Goods@45322aea]> but was:<[Goods@149fac29]>
java.lang.AssertionError: expected same:<[Goods@34c636a7]> was not:<[Goods@59797c7]>

When I try assertTrue(object.equals(testObject)) I get java.lang.AssertionError
**EDIT**
    Debugging expected  Sun Aug 21 16:19:10 EDT 2016 price  3.7 status HIM
 name Product_A 
 actual Product_A HIM 3.7 Sun Aug 21 16:19:10 EDT 2016

Product_A REDLINE30 3.7 null from the expected object
 Product_A REDLINE30 3.7 null from the actual object

But I still get the AssertionError.
Do you know how I can get more information details of the Object from an assertion failure?

Comment: `Assert.assertEquals` uses `equals`; `Assert.assertSame` uses `==`; neither use `compareTo`, since most classes don't implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Also: `o.getProductName() == this.getProductName()`: very dubious.

Comment: @Andy I updated the question with .equals but I am still getting that the objects are not aligned.

Comment: @April_Nara that isn't necessary. If you want to see the difference between two objects, I have had a lot of success using [org.unitils.ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals](http://unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/reflectionassert/ReflectionAssert.html#assertReflectionEquals). It will tell you exactly what the difference between two objects is when it fails.

Comment: @Adam thanks I asserted with a True statement and a custom function in my class.  I remember limitations on that assert that I believe wouldn't have attribute equality requirements reviewed correctly but yes again I could have made mention of some of the out there reasons in verbatim for posting the question

Answer (score 2):

`Assert.assertSame` doc says:

```
Asserts that two objects refer to the same object.
```

Two objects can be equal (`object1.equals(obejct2)`) without being the same reference.

Comment: Have you tried with `Assert.assertTrue(object1.equals(object2))`?

Comment: ok so that's even more with less information to what is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "that's even more"? From what I can gather, sounds like your `equals` method isn't working. I notice in your `compareTo` you are using `==` to compare what I assume are `String` objects (`status` and `name`). You may want to switch to using `.equals()`.

Comment: I keep getting the same thing where I can call the function that gets something .equals(expected)  but the Assertion Statement still 'Error'.

Comment: Sounds like you need to debug and step through the code to inspect each comparison.